# How many writes does appengine do to update an existing entity's list property?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing "Existing Entity Put (per entity) needs 1 Write + 4 Writes per modified indexed property value + 2 Writes per modified composite index value"

So when I insert a new element to a 1000 elements list property and put it back, it will take 4004 writes on this property. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, thats correct. Every list property value has it's own index entry.